# How to view the DOM in WebKit Inspector?

Tags: html, dom, webkit, browser

Is there a way to see the DOM members for an element in WebKit Inspector? I am looking for a similar feature to Firebug's DOM-tab.

Comment: http://www.darcynorman.net/2006/01/17/new-dom-css-inspector-in-safari/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Properties tab is the closest equivalent:

[image: WebKit inspector screenshot]

Note that since I use a nightly build, your interface may not look exactly the same, but it should be there.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to see that from the Console tab? Let's say you type "window" in it.

Comment: @rFactor Typing "window" in the Console tab should bring up an unfoldable structure of every rooted object.